# Reading PDF vector shapes

Tags: c#, pdf, autocad, dwg

I want my C# application to load pdf files, that are originally were exported from DWG or DXF formats, and read the vector shapes in this pdf (e.g Lines, Polylines, Circles, ... etc).

I can make use of these vectors by converting them to entities stored in memory, and reference them to a base point so I can redraw them again using external CAD tool.

Is there any tool that can help me achieve that?

Comment: Answer: Yes, there are plenty of tools.

Comment: I found plenty of tools for reading texts, raster images, but didn't find any for reading vectors.
can u give me some names?

Comment: It depends on what you are exactly trying to do, what data structure and how are you planning to detect, recognize and store Lines, Polylines.. etc

Comment: I can store these vectors using simple classes. eg. I can read a base point and relate all vectors to this base point, and then I can store each shape with it's relative coordinates, lengths and inclination

Comment: AutoCAD have a feature to converto "well printed" PDFs into DWG, why not use it?

Comment: actually I'm using Teigha, which is a library for writing and reading DWG/DGN files, and I was doing just fine till the team leader asked me to include reading PDF files as well and then redraw all the shapes on Teigha viewer control that is already used in our application.
So I can't use AutoCAD at all

Comment: You can use any PDF library to read all the data. If you can't extract shapes try to find another library. After that you'll be able to convert read entities into DGN entities.

Comment: @KyleKhalaf Great, care to suggest even one?